# Typescript 1.8 version in Aurelia Framework

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, aurelia, typescript1.8

I am using Aurelia framework. Last night I updated typescript from 1.7 to 1.8 version.

Now I am getting a lot of errors in the error list tab of visual studio.

Errors like:

```
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(83,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'configurable'.
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(84,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'enumerable'.
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(85,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts(86,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'writable'.
```

There are around 20k errors.

I added code to exclude folders in the tsconfig.json but somehow visual studio is not ignoring those folders.

Below are the snapshot for the jspm_packages folder and npm folder.
[image: jspm_packages]
[image: npm]

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kabaehr buddy all the packages are up-to date.

Comment: The error means that you have double typescript definition files. Check if you have several versions of an package e.g. aurelia-binding under `jspm_packages`. If yes, delete the whole folder and reinstall the packages with `jspm install`

Comment: @kabaehr I have tried, not working. :(

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from your jspm_packages?

Comment: @kabaehr I have added the snapshots for jspm_packages and npm.
Please have a look and tell me know your comments.

Comment: Is this still an issue with the improvements in the last year?